# callbackFlow not returning anything android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement firebase realtime database with coroutines, so I need to use flow because firebase just accept callbacks. the problem is the .collect{} block never gets executed
here is my code

```
   @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
override suspend fun getProduct(barcode: String): ProductItem? {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        println("Hi")
        var item: ProductItem? = null
        productFlow(barcode).collect {
        //this never gets called
            print("Getting product")
            item = it
        }
        println("Ending product request ${item?.name}")
        Log.i("GetProduct",item?.name)
        item
    }
}
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
private fun productFlow(barcode: String): Flow<ProductItem?> = callbackFlow {
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    val productRef = database.getReference("products/$barcode")
    val callback = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for(snapshot in dataSnapshot.children){

                Log.i("Source", snapshot.value.toString())
            }
            val product = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProductItem::class.java)
            Log.i("Source",product?.name) //everything is good until here

            sendBlocking(dataSnapshot.getValue(ProductItem::class.java)) //after this i dont get anything on the collect{} block
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            println("cancelling")
            sendBlocking(null)
        }
    }
    try {
        productRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(callback)
    } catch (e: FirebaseException) {
        println("Firebase exception")
        sendBlocking(null)
    }
    awaitClose{
        println("Closing")
        productRef.removeEventListener(callback)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would suggest to use the `catch` method to check if there is an error or not. Second, for `callbackflow` I remember using `offer()` instead of `sendBlocking`

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't work either, i don't get amy errors on the new try catch either so I don't know :(

Comment: Then, you can open an issue at coroutines github :/

Comment: Now that I think about it, since you only have an evaluation, for your case it could be easier to use a `suspendCancelableCoroutine` instead of a `callbackFlow`

Comment: thanks, I'll try it out later, I fixed it this morning by saying channel.close() after the sendBlocking statement because there is no onComplete callback from firebase and i just need to retrieve once. but I'll try it out and come back

Comment: @ cshjsc Thanks! I had had the same issue. After `channel.close()` adding my issue has been corrected